# Rails migration - add unique index allowing skipping null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

I wanted like to add unique constraint to column `name` in existing table psql

created table (PostgreSQL) :

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.timestamps null: true
    end
    add_index :requests, :user_id
  end
end
```

So I added validation uniqueness in model

```
class Request < ModelBase
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true
  ...
```

and migration like this:

```
def change
    add_index :user_requests, :name, unique: true
end
```

but I noticed that in some cases name can be empty can I add_index with condition were `:name` is null / not null?

Edit: yes, I want those empty values to stay in the database (I don't need to modify past request). I think that I need to edit migration to be more accurate to the actual state of db.

Comment: Yes, You can do it by using validates :name, :presence => true, uniqueness: true

Comment: I want to have some values null ;) or rather I don't need to change past empty names :)

Comment: In which condition do you want null?

Comment: so I have `add_index :user_requests, :name, unique: true` I'm thinking about sth like if name is added should be unique (but can be empty)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No one answer so I'm adding my solution
migration should look like that:

```
def change
    add_index :user_requests, :name, unique: true, where: 'name IS NOT NULL'
end
```

(validation still: 
`validates :name, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true`)

Comment: Null and empty are not the same so we can add "(name IS NOT NULL) OR (name != '')" in the index, like this: 
add_index :user_requests, :name, unique: true, where: "(name IS NOT NULL) OR (name != '')"

Answer (score 6):

Use following

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true, if: 'name.present?'
```

For index may be you try

```
add_index :user_requests, :name, unique: true, where: 'name IS NOT NULL'
```

Comment: this is same like `allow_blank`?

Answer (score 0):

proper format to make uniqueness

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},format: { without: /\s/,message: 'is invalid (spaces are not allowed)'}
```

Comment: thanks - but I added wrong description I guess - I know how to make them unique and allow empty in model (`validates :name, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true`), but I'm thinking about this migration above

Comment: @eudaimonia you can do this by `null:false` while creating table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true,
```

Where, **presence: true** will validate for empty or not and **uniqueness: true** will validate for unique name of user.

Comment: I want some values empty

Comment: Can you explain me in more details so i can help you ?

Answer (score -3):

Add `presence: true` also 
like

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
```

You can add default value in your migration like

```
class AddDefaultToRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :requests, :name, default: ''
  end

  def down
    change_column :requests, :name
  end
end
```

Comment: I know this, but I think about skipping empty values - they can occurs

Comment: you can add in your migration 'default ' value